# Plotting row by row together with two fixed rows.

Tags: r, ggplot2

As the title says I would like to do some line plots. Let's use the `mtcars` as an example.

I would like to plot in total 10 rows from this data set. I chose those ones:

```
> dput(vec)
c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", 
"Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", 
"Merc 280")
```

So first of all I decided to subset the whole data set:

```
tbl_mtcars <- mtcars[row.names(mtcars) %in% vec, ]
```

and than I would like to plot those rows but with the assumption that on each plot there will be only 3 lines. The lines for Merc 230 and Merc 280 should always be on the plot and the rest should be added one by one.

Would be great if that could be done with `ggplot`:

The function below is just the example of code which I often use for plotting.

```
ggplot(tbl_mtcars, aes(gear, carb, group=factor(Name))) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  geom_line(aes(color=factor(Name))) +
  ggtitle("Title")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding "one by one". So you want to create several (how many?) plots, or facets?

Comment: also, how do you want to plot lines with only one x and y value?

Comment: The data set which I am going to plot is different. I just used the mtcars to show how I select the rows which should be plotted. I can't share the real data. By adding "one by one" I mean to create few plots. So if the data contains 10 rows (including those two fixed) that means there will be 8 graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `mtcars` might not be the best dataset to illustrate your need. Instead, I created a data frame of 10 rows and 5 columns (representing observations).

The thing is, `ggplot` needs a specific form of data ('long' instead of 'wide'), so before we can draw a graph, we need to modify the data first. Here I use `melt` from `reshape2` package.

Now we can generate the plots while keeping in mind the two fix rows (IDs) you mentioned. Here, the last two IDs are fixed. Please note that I only present the vanilla-type of plots here, without much cosmetics.

(EDIT/UPDATE: as per @Paul Hiemstra's suggestion, replacing `for` loop with `lapply` and removing `eval-parse` combination, although still keeping the `grid.arrange` method)

```
# Generate data: 10 IDs each with 5 observations
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50), 10, 5))
df$id <- as.numeric(rownames(df))

# Melt the data
require(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = "id")

# Generate plots
require(ggplot2)
plot.list <- lapply(1:(max(df2$id)-2), function(i) {
  df2.i <- df2[df2$id %in% c(i, 9, 10), ]
  ggplot(df2.i) +
    geom_line(aes(x = as.numeric(variable), y = value, colour = factor(id)))
})

# Combine plots
require(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange, plot.list)
```

[image: output: eight graphs]

Comment: I would avoid using the `for` loop, and use `lapply` in stead. Also, please avoid use `assign` to save the objects in the global workspace, simply saving it as a `list` works much better. This also avoids having to use the very ugly and error prone `eval`-`parse` combination. Finally, see my answer for a way to use `ggplot` facetting to make the same image and avoid `grid.arrange`.

Comment: Thank you for the input, really appreciate it. I modified my code as per your suggestion, although it still utilizes the `grid.arrange` method.

Comment: What about my `id` being character ? I can't use `max` in that case. Do you know how this problem can't be solved ?

Comment: @ShaxiLiver you can use nrow(df2) or length(df2$id) for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

After some data manipulation you can use the same dataset as @zyurnaidi, but using facetting and not `grid.arrange`. The trick is to use two `geom_line`'s and `facet_wrap`. The first `geom_line` draws the lines you always want to see, the second the varying line.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 = as.data.frame(t(df)) %>% 
  gather(variable_id, value, -V9, -V10) %>% 
  gather(always_show_id, value_always, V9, V10) %>% 
  group_by(variable_id, always_show_id) %>% mutate(x_id = seq_len(length(variable_id)))
head(df2)
  variable_id       value always_show_id value_always x_id
1          V1 -0.89596500             V9   -0.1758441    1
2          V1  0.42307486             V9   -0.2183904    2
3          V1 -1.13538973             V9    0.3609882    3
4          V1 -0.05927355             V9   -0.3902112    4
5          V1 -0.69209362             V9    0.1045214    5
6          V2 -0.56098448             V9   -0.1758441    1

df2 %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x_id, y = value_always, group = always_show_id)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x_id, y = value), color = 'red') + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable_id)
```

[image]