# Plot multiple rows on the same graph - few graphs on the same page

Tags: r, plot

It's a bit of follow up of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155685/plotting-row-by-row-together-with-two-fixed-rows/37161881#37161881):

This time I would like to export my graphs into pdf and I would like to have 6 graphs on the same page. Why 6, because I have 6 different data sets:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50), 10, 15))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30), 10, 15))
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 5))
df4 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(70), 10, 5))
df5 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(110), 10, 10))
df6 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(70), 10, 10))
```

I changed the row.names to be make the example data more similar to real one:

```
row.names(df1) <- c("Mark", "Tere", "Marcus", "Heidi", "Georg", "Tieme", "Joan", "Tytus", "Julius", "Crater")
df1$id <- rownames(df1)
```

Addition of `id` column is necessary for the code which I use for plotting (`ggplot`).

NOW, to get to the point. So as you see all the data sets have exactly the same `row.names` but they might be in different order! Pointing out my expections could be easier to understand:

**1.** I would like to create a separate graph for each of the data set but all of them (6 in total) should be on the same page.

**2.** Each of the graph should have 3 plots (3 lines - look at the previous thread I created).

**3.** Plot for `Heidi` and `Joan` must be on all of the graphs and with one additional (look again to previous thread). It means there should be one page for each of the other names from this data.

**4.** It would be appreciated if it would be done with `ggplot`.

Just to make it easier to understand:

6 graphs in total. Each graph contains `Heidi` , `Joan` + any other (Marcus/Tieme/Georg/Julius/etc). Each page for different name.

That's a code which I use for plotting each of the row together with 2 constant:

```
pdf(file = sprintf("Df_plots.pdf", df1), paper='A4r')

lapply(1:length(df1$numb), function (i) {
  df1_melted.i <- df1_melted[df1_melted$numb %in% c(i, Heidi, Joan),]
  ggplot(data_plot2.i) +
    geom_line(aes(x = as.numeric(variable), y = value, colour = factor(id)))
})

dev.off()
```

It sound complicated but it should be really easy task for someone with the R experience.

EDIT:

```
df1$numb <- 1:length(row.names(df1))
df1_melted <- melt(df1, id.vars = c("id", "numb))
```

EDIT:

edited data with different number of columns.

[image: Desired output]

I would like to have the plots arranged like that. You have to take to the account that number of columns will be different - more values.

Comment: What are df_plot, tbl_plot , data_melted?

Comment: Slightly edited the code. It was just an example of the code which can be used/edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to match your example a little better.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50), 10, 10))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30), 10, 10))
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 5))
df4 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(70), 10, 5))
df5 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(110), 10, 15))
df6 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(70), 10, 15))

data <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6)

all_names <- c("Mark", "Tere", "Marcus", "Heidi", "Georg", "Tieme", "Joan", "Tytus", "Julius", "Crater")

for (i in seq_along(data)){
  # Adding number of columns
  data[[i]]$n_col <- ncol(data[[i]])

  # Adding the random order row names
  data[[i]]$id <-sample(all_names, 10) 

  # Adding a data frame number column
  data[[i]] <- cbind(data[[i]], frame = i)
}

df <- plyr::rbind.fill(data) %>%
  gather(time, value, -id, -frame, -n_col) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(time = gsub('X', '', time) %>% as.numeric)

plot_name <- function(name){
  df %>% 
    filter(id %in% c('Heidi', 'Joan', name)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    aes(x = time, y = value, group = id, colour = id) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(frame ~ n_col, scales = 'free_x', nrow = 3, ncol = 2) +
    theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.text.x = element_blank())
}

pdf(file = sprintf("Df_plots.pdf", df1), paper='A4r')

for (name in setdiff(all_names, c('Heidi', 'Joan'))){
  print(plot_name(name))
  #grid.newpage()
}

dev.off()
```

Comment: Looks ok for the test data. I will test in a minute with my real data. Do you get every second page in pdf blank ?

Comment: Nope, it's every page for me. Does it work with the real data?

Comment: It works. I had to slightly modified my data but the code works. Still have the problem with blank pages.

Comment: I do not want to create next thread but I still face a small problem. The data sets which I use have different columns number which means the graphs should be different in size. Using the code you made I still can see what I want but it is not ideal. Do you have any solution for that ? I can offer you a bounty of 50 points.

Comment: Sure I could give it a go. Give me some time!

Comment: I've edited my answer so it works with dataframes of different sizes. Let me know how you get on with it!

Comment: Also, I am now getting blank pages - but it's because the plot is large enough to take up a whole page itself. Removing grid.newpage() will fix that

Comment: Hmm... it looks different but still it is not like my desired output. I put the desired output in the first post.

Comment: Can you use `par(mfrow=c(3,2))`?

Comment: I've once again edited my answer. I'm not 100% sure what you want but have a look at what I've done and tell me if it looks okay or what needs to change.

Comment: Definitely deserved 50 points of the bounty! That's awesome! Need to wait 6h before I accept the bounty.